# Improving the imports in Webstorm 11 using JSPM and Typescript

Tags: typescript, webstorm, angular, jspm

I am using JSPM and Typescript for an Angular2 project and Webstorm 11 seems confused about the import paths of the TS classes.

[image]

The first import is the correct one:

`import {Component} from "angular2/core";`

But the other two are referencing directly from the `jspm_packages` folder importing this two paths incorectly:

```
import {Component} from "../../jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.0/src/core/metadata";
import {Component} from "../../jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.0/ts/src/core/metadata";
```

I have ignored both `node_modules` and `jspm_packages` in `tsconfig.json` as Webstorm seems to recognize it, but no luck so far.

Is there any way i can configure Webstorm to automatically import the correct module and ignore the other two?

Comment: you have 3 imports importing Component in the same file?

Comment: No, I have none and Webstorm is trying to auto import it (alt+enter).

Comment: ah :D sadly I can't help you with that :(

Answer (score 1):

jspm is currently not supported by Webstorm. But node.js is. If you install angular2 via npm the imports work:

```
npm i angular2@2.0.0-beta.2 es6-promise@^3.0.2 es6-shim@^0.33.3 reflect-metadata@0.1.2 rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0 zone.js@0.5.10 --save
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, but this way if you are using jspm you would have to define the packages both in the `jspm config` and and `npm dependencies`.